# I've created a html content box but its not responsive, what should i do to convert it into responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

its a simple html content box with logos. it looks good on desktop but not on mobile. it must be responsive. it i add meta viewport, it looks weird. here is my code. what I've to change here to convert these boxes into responsive

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
} 
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
} 
.card:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 40px;
} 
.card:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 40px;
} 
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 40px;
} 
body:hover .card {
  filter: blur(15px);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.9s;
} 
body .card:hover{
  filter:blur(0);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.9s;
}

img{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  margin:20px 0px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 20px 60px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
} 
#circle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -330px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 200px;
} 
#triangle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: rotate(70deg);
  margin-top: -430px;
  margin-left: 200px;
} 
.content a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding:6px 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <title>CSS Creative Product Card UI Design | E commerce Card Using Html5 & CSS3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    

    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
        
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 
    
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

what i've to change here to conver these boxes into responsive one.waiting for help...

Comment: The first part of responsiveness is to stop using fixed pixel sizes everywhere. Use percentage widths or other similar values.

Answer (score 0):

**Add flex-wrap:wrap; in your body selector**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
} 
.main-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
} 
body:hover .card {
  filter: blur(15px);
  transform: scale(0.9);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.9s;
} 
body .card:hover{
  filter:blur(0);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.9s;
}

img{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  margin:20px 0px 0px 20px;
  float: left;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 20px 60px 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
} 
#circle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: -330px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-right: 200px;
} 
#triangle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: rotate(70deg);
  margin-top: -430px;
  margin-left: 200px;
} 
.content a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding:6px 15px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 10px 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <title>CSS Creative Product Card UI Design | E commerce Card Using Html5 & CSS3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
    
  <div class="main-container">
    
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
        
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 
    
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working, but space between the cards is too large, how can i reduce it

Comment: Check this https://codepen.io/muhaymin-khan/pen/YzGVLwo and check responsive on mobile device by using inspect element.....

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're not using the css library. If so, you should apply the responsive type using media queries as shown below.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { body { background-color: lightgreen; } }
```

Answer (score -1):

That's happening because your body `display` is set to `flex`, you need to change it to `block` in mobile, so:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
   body {
      display: block;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using bootstrap it will help you a lot to make responsive web pages. in this answer i am just providing you main div responsive other things you check [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#:%7E:text=Bootstrap%20includes%20a%20responsive%2C%20mobile,for%20generating%20more%20semantic%20layouts.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <title>CSS Creative Product Card UI Design | E commerce Card Using Html5 & CSS3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
        
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div id="circle"></div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://www.naijaloaded.com.ng/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/PNG-Image-225-%C3%97-225-pixels-1.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px;">
      </div>
      <p style="text-align: justify;">
        PrintAll is here to bring a new standard of quality and services for online commercial printing. It’s a fast growing online printing and creative firm with a proven track record of delivering the best solutions to our customers. We can offer the best pricing, integrated dealing, finer quality and service.</p>
      <div class="content">
        <a>More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```